# Cakephp get SELECT's value and text by jquery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I have tried to get value from select option in cakephp,Here is my code

```
 echo $this->Form->input('division', array('type' => 'select',
                                           id=>'my-select',
                                          'options' =>   array('Dhaka' => 'Dhaka', 'Dinajpur' => 'Dinajpur','Others'=>'Others'),'selected' => 'Dhaka'));
```

Here is my js code

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my-select").change(function() {
        alert($('#my-select option:selected').html());
    });
});
</script>
```

Problem is no any feed back given.I am enable to find error.Where is the problem ?

Comment: try by putting the js code in $(document).ready(function(){ //your js code here  });

Comment: I have used it.But not working.

Comment: I don't know anything about CakePHP, but provided that your PHP is creating the correct HTML, your JS code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9AZLw/. Check your source code in your browser. What does your HTML look like?

Comment: check this alert($(this).val())

Comment: I think @sandip is right. Use `alert($(this).val());` instead of `alert($('#my-select option:selected').html());`

Comment: First try with normal HTML select box, so we can find out whether the issues is with your javascript or cakephp html helper.

Comment: @CJRamki: Well, there's a key difference here. For the case pointed out in this question, the point is moot, but for general purposes, there's a difference. The way the OP has it written, it would alert the contents between the `<option></option>` tags. Using `$(this).val()` will alert the `value` attribute. Doesn't matter for the OP's question, since his values are the same as his option contents, but for the general case, there's a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use *.on()* in jquery. Cakephp rendered dom elements dynamically.

```
$(document).on("change" , "#my-select" , function() {
    alert($('#my-select option:selected').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my-select").on('change',function(e){
     var select_value = $(e.currentTarget).val();
     alert(select_value);
  });
});
```